# Difference between Parentheses for Capturing and Back References in Perl

Tags: perl

I'm just starting to learn Perl, and I wanted to know the difference between parentheses for capturing and back references in Perl, and what situations where each one would be more useful?

When I say parentheses for capturing, I'm referring to something like the following:

```
if ($email =~ /([^@]+)@(.+)/) {
    print "Username is $1\n";
    print "Hostname is $2\n";
}
```

When I say back referencing, I'm refering to something like the following:

```
# (.)\1
# (.) = capture group; \1 = reference group
# (.)(.)\2\1; This pattern has 2 capture groups
# (.)(.)\g{2}\g{1}; This pattern is safer. Can't be confused w/ digits
```

If my syntax is incorrect w\ the back referencing, please let me know because I'm not 100% sure how the syntax works for back referencing.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A part of a regex pattern enclosed in parentheses will be *captured* if the pattern as a whole matches. It is irrelevant how that captured substring is used. Captures are numbered starting from 1 from left to right in the order that their opening parenthesis appear in the regex pattern

- It may be used as a *back-reference* later on inside the same pattern by using the sequence `\1` etc. or (preferably) `\g1` etc.
- It may be used *outside* the pattern as a simple string value `$1` etc. either in the replacement part of a substitution or in subsequent Perl code

You can use the captured string in both ways at once, for instance

```
say $1 if $str =~ /(.)\g1/;
```

Note that if the pattern fails to match, the value of `$1` will be *unchanged* from the most recent successful match, so any use of `$1` etc. should be conditional on the successful match of the pattern from which it is to be drawn

Answer (score 2):

There is no difference.  Parentheses capture (unless it's one of the `(?...)` constructs).  You can use the captured text as a backreference or with capture variables (`$1`) (or both).

Comment: So the difference between the two is the syntax we use to call the text within the parentheses?

Answer (score 1):

There is no difference. There aren't even two things two compare. There's just `(...)`.

It can be used to backreference. `\1` is a regular expression atom that matches what the first capture captured. This can only be used in regular expression patterns.

It can be used to capture. `$1` is a Perl variable that contains what the first capture captured. This can only be in used in Perl code.